# How do I go about making multiple instances of links in changing content work?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a content slideshow of sorts and having issues getting the links in the changed content to work properly. The first one calls the next frame properly, but the links in subsequent frames do not work at all. My code thus far is below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="overlaycontent">
  Welcome, enjoy your stay!
  <a class="mylink" data="demo" href="#">Get Started!</a>
</div>

<div id="helpDemo" style="display:none;"> This would be content 1 <a class="helplink" data="acts" href="#">Next</a> </div>
<div id="helpActs" style="display:none;"> This would be content 2 <a class="helplink" data="more" href="#">Next</a> </div>
<div id="helpMore" style="display:none;"> This would be content 3  </div>


$(".helplink").on("click",function(e){
  if($(this).attr('data') == 'demo'){ 
    $('.overlaycontent').html($('#helpDemo').html());
  }
  if($(this).attr('data') == 'acts'){
    $('.overlaycontent').html($('#helpActs').html());
  }
  if($(this).attr('data') == 'more'){
    $('.overlaycontent').html($('#helpMore').html());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<a class="mylink" data="demo" href="#">Get Started!</a>
```

to

```
<a class="helplink" data="demo" href="#">Get Started!</a>
```

AND

```
$(".helplink").on("click",function(e){
```

to

```
$(".overlaycontent").on("click",".helplink",function(e){
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LzUdd/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you have to delegate the click on .helplink because when you are on the second slide you manipulated the DOM ->

do like :

```
    $(document).on("click",".helplink",function(){
  if($(this).attr('data') == 'demo'){ 
    $('.overlaycontent').html($('#helpDemo').html());
  }
  if($(this).attr('data') == 'acts'){
    $('.overlaycontent').html($('#helpActs').html());
  }
  if($(this).attr('data') == 'more'){
    $('.overlaycontent').html($('#helpMore').html());
  }         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on here will take a few steps!

First, `$(".helplink").on(...)` will find all *current* elements with the `.helplink` class, and attach events to them.

Second, using `.html(...)` to "copy" the content only copies the source HTML. Any properties set on them, especially event handlers, are not copied.

This means that the new content of the main content area does not have events attached, and therefore the links do not work.

To fix, try `$(document.body).on("click",".helplink",function(e) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding the onclick event listener at the start, you're adding it to the existing DOM.  Once you've modified the DOM it doesn't keep the manipulated events, and you'll need to re-apply them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using proprietary attributes, which is invalid, you can set the `id` of the element to show in the `href` attribute of the link. Try this:

```
<div class="overlaycontent">
    Welcome, enjoy your stay! 
    <a class="mylink helplink" href="#helpDemo">Get Started!</a>
</div>

<div id="helpDemo" style="display:none;">
    This would be content 1 
    <a class="helplink" href="#helpActs">Next</a> 
</div>
<div id="helpActs" style="display:none;">
    This would be content 2 
    <a class="helplink" href="#helpMore">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="helpMore" style="display:none;">
    This would be content 3
</div>
```

```js
$(".overlaycontent").on('click', ".helplink", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.overlaycontent').html($(ref).html());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpY8u/)

It makes the JS much simpler, and much easier to maintain should you need to add more div elements to show at a later date.